# Issue with muilti-threading with pthread: thread is executing prematurely

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I am trying to call make a thread to another function in a function being ran by a child process. I am starting by calling a child process, which makes another child process, which in turn makes a thread. However, the thread function keeps executing prematurely. What could be the issue?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <pthread.h> // pthread
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>// waitpid
#include <sys/wait.h> //waitpid
#define STACK_Size 1024*1024

void* print(void* ptr)
{ 
  printf("\n4. In thread\n");
  char* message;
  message = (char*)ptr;
  printf("\n5. Message from parent: %s \n\n",message);
}

static int threading(void * ptr)
{ 
  char* message;
  message = (char*)ptr;
  printf("\n3. In child process 2\n");
  pthread_t Tid;
  pthread_create(&Tid,NULL,&print,(void*)message);
  pthread_join(Tid,NULL);
  printf("\n6. Thread done.... exiting child process 2\n\n");
}


static int child(void *ptr)
{
  char* message;
  message = (char*) ptr;
  print("\n2. In child 1");
  // creating child process
  char* stack_ptr = malloc(STACK_Size);
  unsigned long flags =0;
   pid_t pid;
   pid = clone(threading, stack_ptr+STACK_Size,flags | SIGCHLD,message);
    int status;
    waitpid(pid,&status,0);
    printf("7. Done with child 2\n\n8. Now exiting child process 1\n"); 
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
 char msg[150];
 printf("1. Currently in main program name: %s\n", argv[0]);
 sprintf(msg,"The name of the program is (%s), P.S this is parent (pid:%d)",argv[0],getpid());
 char* stack_pointer = malloc(STACK_Size);
 unsigned long flags =0;
 setbuf(stdout,NULL);
 if((argc >1) && (strcmp(argv[1],"vm")==0))
 {
  flags = CLONE_VM;
 }
 pid_t pid;
 pid = clone(child,stack_pointer+STACK_Size,flags | SIGCHLD,msg);
 int status;
 waitpid(pid,&status,0);
 printf("\n9. Done with Parent process\n");
}
```

Here is the output it's producing:

```
1. Currently in main program name: ./clone
    
4. In thread
    
5. Message from parent: 
2. In child 1 
    
    
3. In child process 2
    
4. In thread
    
5. Message from parent: The name of the program is (./clone), P.S this is parent (pid:15159) 
    
    
6. Thread done.... exiting child process 2
    
7. Done with child 2
    
8. Now exiting child process 1
    
9. Done with Parent process
```

Comment: Do you enforce order somehow? If not, you don't have guarantees when something runs. A started thread could finish before the call that started it even returns. Also, your description is very confusing. In particular, I wonder whether you couldn't erase the multiprocessing. Also, why are you mixing that with threads to begin with? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: There is no point to launching a single thread and then immediately joining it, as your `threading()` function does.  It is better in just about every way to simply call the thread function directly.

Comment: Why are you using Linux-specific `clone()` instead of POSIX-standard `fork()`?  The former is a bit more flexible, but less portable and harder to use correctly, and you're not making use of any of that added flexibility.

Comment: "keeps executing prematurely" What does it mean exactly? What do you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by executing prematurely is the lines containing `4.` and `5.` being printed before `2.`, it's because you call your custom `print()` function to output `2.` (`print("\n2. In child 1")`) which also prints out `4.` and `5.`.